# Characterize the following sets as closed/open in the space of M2(R)

Tags: general-topology

Characterize the  following sets as closed/open in the space of $M_2(R)$(topologized by considering it as a subset of euclidean space of dimension $4$ in the obvious way   )

Set of matrices of the type:-
i)\begin{bmatrix}
1&x\\
0&1
\end{bmatrix}

ii)\begin{bmatrix}
1&x\\
0&-1
\end{bmatrix}

iii)
\begin{bmatrix}
a&b\\
0&c
\end{bmatrix}

I am trying to think of them as inverse images of continuous maps ,but i cannot think of any map.

Comment: I suppose you mean identifying $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ with $\mathbb{R}^4$ in the obvious way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider the coordinate maps $x_{ij}:M_2(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ for $1\leq i,j\leq2$ you can see the sets as

i) $x_{11}^{-1}(1)\cap x_{22}^{-1}(1)\cap x_{21}^{-1}(0)$

ii) $x_{11}^{-1}(1)\cap x_{22}^{-1}(-1)\cap x_{21}^{-1}(0)$

iii) $x_{11}^{-1}(a)\cap x_{12}^{-1}(b)\cap x_{21}^{-1}(0)\cap x_{22}^{-1}(c)$